# Wordpress + REST API + featured_image

Tags: images, rest-api

I currently have a WordPress blog with images stored in an S3 AWS bucket.

I upload the images directly to the S3 bucket "manually".

I have a text file with the image urls for each post.

These posts do not exist yet on my WordPress blog.

I thought I would use the Wordpress REST API to create the posts in WordPress.

I thought that I could add the url for my image in the field "featured_media". But it seems this field wants the id of the image. I have no id.

Do you know how I can use the api to allocate these images as featured_media when I create a new post?

Apologies if it is a silly question - I'm not familiar with the API (or wordpress).

Comment: if it requires an image ID, then you need an image ID. So you'll need to add the image as media on your site, then use the ID in your post. This would be a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671683/upload-media-to-wordpress-using-rest-api

Comment: but then WordPress will be trying to serve the image itself rather from S3, so you'll need a S3 image offload plugin or some custom hooks and metadata to sort that out too.